# How does the Crawl Component propagate the Index to the Query component

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, infrastructure

I'm investigating how SharePoint Server 2010 search works, especially which technique is used to propagate the index (generated by the crawler) to the query server.
In SP2007 the index was stored locally and copied to the query server(s) using UNC, as far as I know.
In SP2010 this changes and no local copy is preserved. But, how is it copied / streamed to the Query server? Using UNC? Using web services?

None of the diagrams / technet articles / blogs I've seen explained this in detail, it's just saying "the crawler propagates / streams the index to the query server".

Comment: check this one https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b6e5d9d-cdc9-48a7-8d9a-a2d3b8a3343d/how-works-propagation-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointsearchprevious

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any documentation but looks like it is using the networkpath to move the index files to query server. I think it is same as it was in Moss 2007.

Check the below blog and the error the person getting the idea.

> 01-14-2012 12:00:12.48 OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0958) 0x09B8 SharePoint Server
>   Search Administration f6ql Warning The following conditions are
>   currently affecting index propagation to this server for search
>   service application 'Partitioned Search':   1. Query 1, catalog Main:
>   failing to copy index files from crawl component 1 for 105658 minutes.
>   The network path was not found.   0x80070035  2. Query 1 is not being
>   automatically disabled because the minimum number of ready query
>   components per partition is 2. d39bcb4a-a193-427f-9fcc-f65cd6127a73

http://sharepointmadeeasy.blogspot.com/2012/06/sharepoint-2010-search-query-component.html

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b6e5d9d-cdc9-48a7-8d9a-a2d3b8a3343d/how-works-propagation-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointsearchprevious

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. So, there should be file transfer possible between SP Servers. Our network settings are rather tight, so I must state every port that requires to be open.

Comment: I am in big favor of , no firewall between servers...

Comment: That's another discussion. We have the policy that not every port is open between servers.

Comment: search is using  TCP 16500-16519 for intra farm only...you can read more about what ports & services should enabled on server at this technet...http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262849(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thanks, this is different in SP2010: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262849(v=office.14).aspx

File and Printer Sharing service —either of the following, used by search roles:
Direct-hosted SMB (TCP/UDP 445) — this is the recommended port
NetBIOS over TCP/IP (NetBT) (TCP 137, UDP 138, UDP 139) — disable these ports if you do not use it

Comment: You are right, File and Printer Sharing service ports. i oversee the article, i referenced 2013.Mybad. :(

Comment: The 2010 article is invisible. I could only reach it by changing v=office.15 in the URL to v=office.14...